put in data to JSON
I can't add data to JSON file ( read/write (I/O Input)).
its data type is : STR
I don't want it and I want data type  : DICT
with open("users.json","r") as myfile :
result = myfile.read()
print(type(result)) # STR but I want DICT

Please explain to me.

Use the json library

This question is similar to: How can I import a json as a dict?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Try using the json module from the standard library. Say you have a users.json file with the following contents:
{
    "user1": {
        "name": "Alice",
        "age": 25
    },
    "user2": {
        "name": "Bob",
        "age": 28
    }
}

You can read it into a dictionary using json.load and use json.dump to write it back to a file after you modify it:
import json

with open('users.json', 'r') as myfile:
  result = json.load(myfile)

print(f'{result = }')
print(f'{type(result) = }')

result['user3'] = {'name': 'Chuck', 'age': 30}

with open('new_users.json', 'w') as myfile:
  json.dump(result, myfile, indent=4)

Output:
result = {'user1': {'name': 'Alice', 'age': 25}, 'user2': {'name': 'Bob', 'age': 28}, 'user3': {'name': 'Chuck', 'age': 30}}
type(result) = <class 'dict'>

✨ Newly created ✨ new_users.json:
{
    "user1": {
        "name": "Alice",
        "age": 25
    },
    "user2": {
        "name": "Bob",
        "age": 28
    },
    "user3": {
        "name": "Chuck",
        "age": 30
    }
}

